# How the proper way to insert image in "Resources" in Xamarin Project

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I really have problem with adding new images for future use in my project.

- I have tried a few different ways; First just directly copying the picture into the `Resources` folder, which **failed**.
- Then I tried using `Add Files` by right clicking on the `Resources` folder which also **failed**. (I get an error when I try to rebuild the project).[image: Example img of the text above]

This is the error message I get:

[image: theerrormessage]

Here is the `xaml` code that I use to call the image:

```
 <NavigationPage Icon="cny.png" Title="CNY Deals">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AboutPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: Offtopic, but Xamarin recommends using Visual Studio on both Windows and Mac, Xamarin Studio will no longer be supported. https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.3/xamarin.studio_6.3/

Comment: im using visual studio for mac

Comment: Put the image in Assets.

Answer (score 2):

Just drag and drop the image into Resources folder,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows

In case you want to embed images in 'PCL': change the Build Action in properties of the image to 'Embedded Resource'.

In case of Android: drag and drop the image in 'drawable-hdpi' folder under Resources, and make sure the build action in properties is set to 'AndroidResource'.

Important: make sure image filename is lowercase and without special characters, ex: sky.png (OK)
sky-125_A.png (will fail)